# Unable to determine what type of blank, null, na or anything else in R dataframe

Tags: r, null, na

I have a data frame loaded from an Excel csv. One columns has many "NULL". This is what is showing up when looking at the data in RStudio. When I filter in the RStudio viewer by typing in NULL it gets over 13,000 rows. I've been trying to do the same in code with no luck. I've tried.

```
newSurvey %>%
  filter(is.null(TextAnswerValue))
```

Zero values

```
newSurvey %>%
  filter(is.na(TextAnswerValue))
```

Two values

```
newSurvey %>%
 filter(TextAnswerValue == "")
```

Zero values

```
newSurvey %>%
  filter(length(TextAnswerValue) < 10)
```

Zero values

```
newSurvey %>%
  filter(TextAnswerValue) == NULL)
```

Zero values

Nothing works, not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

```
newSurvey %>%
  filter(TextAnswerValue == "NULL")
```